# How to keep urlpatterns neat

Tags: django

Django==2.2.3

I have a rather big list in urlpatterns. I use namespaces, but urlpatterns are all the same big.

Example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('semantics',
         SemanticsList.as_view(),
         name="semantics"),

    path('common_negative_phrases',
         CommonNegativePhrasesList.as_view(),
         name="common_negative_phrases"),

    path('semantics_level3_minus_phrases/<int:level>/',
         SemanticsLevel3MinusPhrasesList.as_view(),
         name="semantics_level3_minus_phrases"),

    path('semantics_level2_minus_phrases/<int:level>/',
         SemanticsLevel2MinusPhrasesList.as_view(),
         name="semantics_level2_minus_phrases"),

    path('comparative_phrases_list',
         ComparativePhrasesList.as_view(),
         name="comparative_phrases_list"),

    path('transactional_phrases_list',
         TransactionalPhrasesList.as_view(),
         name="transactional_phrases_list"),

    path('info_phrases_list',
         InfoPhrasesList.as_view(),
         name="info_phrases_list"),
]
```

I'd like to keep them more neat. Maybe sort them alphabetically. Any other ideas? As for alphabetic sorting. I wouldn't like to sort them by myself. Maybe there is an online service or something for this purpose?

Comment: You could use `ast` to manipulate your `urls.py` file, yes, but that will probably result in more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: Your urls are not very friendly and could be grouped further: /phrases/comparative/, /phrases/info/, /phrases/transactional/, /phrases/semantic/level_2/ etc... make for clearer URLs. As to how to organise them, I don't see another way than manually.